# How to write Regex to extract decimals with strictly two decimal places where both places is zero from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I have these strings:

- You received $**10.00** from here
- You purchased 0.00400 BCH for Rs.**10.00**
- You got a refund of **10.00** USD
- You got a gift card of **15.00**USD

I want to write a single regex that will **extract the amounts(decimal values with strictly 2 decimal places and has 0 in both places, ie, bolded values)** from these strings, but **it should not extract** **0.00400**. I tried with this regex: `"[0-9]\\d{0,9}(\\.\\d{0,2})(?<!/{1,9}(\\s)?)"`. But, this is not working for every cases. Also, it includes `0.00` from `0.00400`, which is not I want. So, could anyone help me how to edit this pattern to meet my requirements? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you want to match zeros use zeros in the pattern, `"\\d+\\.00(?!\\d)"`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iRnJK/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down.

> `[0-9]\\d{0,9}`

That's a bizarre way to write `\\d{1,9}`. `[0-9]` is 'any character whose unicode value lies between the unicode value of `0` and the unicode value of `9` inclusive, and `\\d` is 'any digit', which boils down to the same thing (`\\d` technically supports non-arabic numerals, but it's usually a good idea to be open to these. In any case, either you want `[0-9]{1,9}` or you want `\\d{1,9}`, and not what you wrote, that's mix and matching which sounds nuts.

> `(\\.\\d{0,2})`

A dot, followed by 0, 1, or 2 digits. You said you want exactly 2 digits, so this should be `\\.\\d{2}`.

> `(?<!/{1,9}(\\s)?)`

Some negative lookbehind - there is absolutely no reason to get into this. Let's not use it all.

Let's start over, this feels like you've gone down the wrong track.

You want a dot, and then 2 zeroes. That's it. Let's just.. do that then:

```
"(\\d+)\\.00(?!\\d)"
```

That's: 1 or more digits, followed by exactly a dot and then two zeroes (which we don't extract, because why extract a constant?), and then we don't care, as long as there isn't a digit there.

Let's run it:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.00(?!\\d)");

public static void tryFind(String in) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    System.out.print(in);
    while (m.find()) System.out.print("  FOUND: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("  END.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    tryFind("You received $10.00 from here");
    tryFind("You purchased 0.00400 BCH for Rs.10.00");
    tryFind("You got a refund of 10.00 USD");
    tryFind("You got a gift card of 15.00USD and 20.00");
    tryFind("Your point balance is 10.0000");
    tryFind("Your next appointment is at 10.00.00 hours");
}
```

produces:

```
You received $10.00 from here  FOUND: 10  END.
You purchased 0.00400 BCH for Rs.10.00  FOUND: 10  END.
You got a refund of 10.00 USD  FOUND: 10  END.
You got a gift card of 15.00USD and 20.00  FOUND: 15  FOUND: 20  END.
Your point balance is 10.0000  END.
Your next appointment is at 10.00.00 hours  FOUND: 10  END.
```

Which is what you want (and note that appointment example, which suggests that what you want is not actually what you want).

Comment: Thanks very much for this beautifully explained answer. By the way, my strings will only have amounts in it. Also here, if u take first string as example, ur pattern returns 10 instead of 10.00. I want 10.00 because my objective is to replace the 10.00 with 10. That's why I need 10.00 because I can remove .00 from 10.00 and replace 10.00 with 10 in the string. Hope u got my point.

Comment: Then perhaps it would have been worthwhile to ask for that, specifically. `in.replaceAll("(\\d{1,9})\\.00(?!\\d)", "$1");` is all you need.